# How to store and retrieve formatted text with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and I am using it to develop a simple personal blog site. The problem I have is that when a blog post is saved as a document to a mongo database, it loses all formatting and is returned as one long paragraph. Is there a way around this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At this state, the question is impossible to answer. Please post some examples: MongoDB documents, how it should look like, how it currently look like, etc.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
const db = getDb();
return db
  .collection('products')
  .find()
  .toArray()
  .then(products => {
    console.log(products);
    return(products);
  })
```